# How to transfer code from codesandbox to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, codesandbox

I am trying to test some code that I want to import into a base website that I already have working in Visual Studio Code. I found a working example of what I am trying to do but wanted to test it in VSC (Visual Studio Code) so I copied and pasted all the files into a new workspace to see if it would work and all that came up when I tested it with the Extension Live Server was a blank screen.

I then though maybe something was wrong and that the extension Live Server couldn't get or read a file some how so I tried recreating it with a nodejs. This is my first time ever using nodejs and it wasn't working either. I just kept getting error after error that I would research try fail and try again and couldn't figure out how to get it working in the end. So I guess what I am asking is if there is an easier way to transfer the code from codesandbox to VSC and have it work with the Live Server extension.

Here is the code from codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-wiles-lil5d?file=/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter way. In codesandbox look for the VS Code icon. you will be asked if you want to open the code in VS Code: Accept and it will be launched in VS Code.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. At least not on 12/21/2023 when I'm trying to do the same. I just get "Sandboxes cannot be opened in VS Code." I don't really want to open the code in vscode. I want to copy it, where I can work with it more easily than in codesandbox. I think I can figure out how to install the dependencies on my own.